# How do you convert from 10s complement to SIGNED decimal?

Tags: arithmetic, number-systems

A bit confused. I am preparing for an exam and one of the practice problems asks us to convert from 10s complement to signed decimal. Attached is the answer to the table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7viJZ.png)

As far as I'm aware and from what I've been taught, converting to and from 10s complement is done using: 1 + (r^n - 1) - x where r is the radix, n is the number of positions, and x is the original number.

I tried that on 48 for example, and I end up getting 52. Something about the "signed" aspect of the decimal number is throwing me off here. I would appreciate if someone explained this.

Thank you.

Comment: I just noticed that $1 + ((r^n-1) - x)$ is a formula for negating an $r$'s complement representation; that is, if $x$ is the $r$'s complement representation for $X$, and you want the $r$'s complement representation for $-X$, you can use this formula. It correctly predicts in this case that the $10$'s complement representation of $-48$ is $52$.

Answer (score 1):

When you have "signed" numbers without an explicit sign -- such as tens complement -- you have to have some other way of telling which numbers are positive and which are negative.

It seems that in this two-digit tens complement system the rule is that if the leftmost of the two digits is $5$ or greater, the number is negative. If the leftmost digit is in anything in the range from $0$ to $4$ inclusive, the number is positive.

Since the leftmost digit of $48$ is $4,$ you have a positive number. Since the number is positive, you do not do take the "tens complement" of it. You just take the number as is. It is simply the positive number $48.$

Answer (score 0):

You take the $10$s complement by first replacing each digit with $9$ minus the digit, and then adding $1$:

The $10$s complement of $3821$ is $$[9-3][9-8][9-2][9-1] + 1 = 6178 + 1 = 6179$$

But notice that if you add $3821 + 6179 = 10000$. This is because if you subtract your original number $3821$ from $9999$, since there is never a need to borrow, you just end up replacing each digit with $9$ minus it. So the conversion becomes
$$3821 \mapsto (9999 - 3821) + 1 = (9999 + 1) - 3821 = 10000 - 3821$$

So the $10$s complement is the same as subtracting your original number from $10^n$, where $n$ is the number of digits available.

For $n = 2$, that means subtracting the original number from $100$. So yes, the $10$s complement of $48$ will be $52$ in a 2-digit system. There are no negative numbers, so the bottom half of the available numbers, $0 - 49$, are used to represent positives, while the top half of the available numbers, $50 - 99$ are used to represent negative numbers.

$0$ is its own negative. The negatives of $1 - 49$ are $100$ minus the positive value, that is, the range $51 - 99$ in reverse order. $50$ is usually also treated as negative, as if it were $-50$. This way you only have to look at the top digit to decide if the number represented is positive or negative: top digits of $0 - 4$ are positive, top digits of $5-9$ are negative.

This works because if you want to subtract $a - b$, that is $a + (-b)$, which in $10$s complement is $a + (100 - b) = 100 + (a-b)$. Since there is no room for the $100$s digit, it is lost, and the stored number is just $a - b$. (Yes, technically in actual systems, the $100$s digit would be stored in an "overflow digit" that could be used in later multi-word calculations. But when doing a simple subtraction, you ignore the overflow digit, so it is still lost.)

Comment: @DavidK - if you had read a little more carefully, you would have noticed that I addressed this. The 2-digit ten's complement is 52 as an *unsigned* integer. The interpretation of this as -48 comes in the re-interpretation of unsigned integers as signed integers. I'm sorry that my description was confusing. I could likely have been more clear with a few drafts to figure out better phrasing, but forum responses tend to be "single draft". But the information is correct. And based on your recent comment to the OP and your own answer, it is based on significantly more experience with the concept.

Comment: $r$'s complement is $r$'s complement. There is only one. The only difference between signed and unsigned is how you interpret the results. The math we are doing is actually just $\bmod r^n$. If you choose $0$ to $r^n-1$ as your equivalence class representatives, then you have unsigned integers. If you choose (for even $r$) $-r^n/2$ to $r^n/2 -1$, you get signed integers. If you compute with an $r$-state machine, then the stored values are exactly the same. The only difference is that for signed you treat the upper half as being the $r$s-complement of the unsigned value.

Comment: This is what I was trying to explain. But I tried too hard to keep the discussion at a lower level, not being sure how much math the OP was comfortable with. The computer science terminology is because two's complement is actually a computer science terminology, and ten's complement is just the extension of that concept to a different base.

Comment: That is was I gave. 48 is stored as 48. The stored digits of -48 are 52. You interpret them as negative by means of the ten's complement. 2 digits are only capable of representing signed integers from -50 to +49.